# JFreechart right click on XYItemEntity

Tags: java, jfreechart

I realized that the chartMouseClicked method gets called only when the user left-clicks on a chart.MousePressed() and mouseReleased() methods are called When when the user right-clicks on a chart. But I need something more. I need them together.I need to find if an user right clicks on XYItemEntity.Then I will show new pop up menu item. If user select menu item, I will pass information from XYITEM. If it is not XYItemEntity, I will not update Popupmenu of chart. That is how can I check XYITEM entity on chartMouseClicked.

```
panel.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListener() {
        public void chartMouseClicked(final ChartMouseEvent event) {
            /** If Time Instance point is clicked */
            if (event.getEntity() instanceof XYItemEntity) {

}}
```

Comment: `ChartMouseEvent::getTrigger` "Returns the mouse event that triggered this event."

Comment: When I right click on chart, no method of  ChartMouseListener is triggered, Methods of MouseListener are called. So  I can not call ChartMouseEvent::getTrigger.What do you think?

Comment: The popup trigger is different on Mac and Windows. You'll probably need a custom `ChartPanel`.

Comment: I don't know another way; `isPopupTrigger()` should be checked in both `mousePressed` and `mouseReleased` for proper cross-platform functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution combining chartMouseMoved and mouseReleased methods.

```
 public void chartMouseMoved(final ChartMouseEvent event) {
            if (event.getEntity() instanceof XYItemEntity) {
                panel.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
                clickedSimulationItem = (XYItemEntity) event.getEntity();
            } else if (event.getEntity() instanceof PlotEntity) {
                handleMouseMoveOnPlot(event);
            } else {
                panel.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
                clickedSimulationItem = null;
            }
        }


private void addMouseListener() {
    panel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                if (clickedSimulationItem != null) {

                        panel.getPopupMenu().add(new JMenuItem("denem"));
                        /** update pop up */
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
```